# Finding all files that contain a string in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, ms-office, microsoft

This should be easy, but for some reason it is alluding me.

For background, I am trying to completely remove Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011 due to a bug that renders the application nearly unusable.

I am at the step where I need to remove all files in the home/Library folder that contain com.microsoft.*.

I cannot perform this simple task in Finder.

In the terminal I did

```
cd ~/Library && find . -name "*com.microsoft*"
```

... but I want to be able to do it in Finder.

Instructions say:

> To remove "com.microsoft" files, follow these steps: On the Go menu,
>   click Home. Open Library. Note The Library folder is hidden in Mac OS
>   X 10.7 and later. To display this folder, hold down the OPTION key
>   while you click the Go menu.
>
> Open Preferences. Arrange files and folders in alphabetical order.
>   Drag all files that begin with "com.microsoft" to the Trash.

... there are only folders directly beneath Library.  So I need to do a recursive search of files.

Is there really no native way to do this in Mac?

Comment: The instructions actually say that you should open the `Preferences` folder within `Library` and remove all files starting with `com.microsoft` from there (basically the same as `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.*`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Search For Property List Files That Contain A String On Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349926/how-to-search-for-property-list-files-that-contain-a-string-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

From the Library folder, a simple search (CMD+F) for `Name` `starting with` `com.microsoft` will recursively find all files and folders in every Library subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

The folder which you are performing the search mustn't be on Spotlight' exception list in order for its items and subitems (files and folders) to be found, even on Finder's search box. You can check this on System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy.