# How To Search For Property List Files That Contain A String On Mac

Tags: mac, finder, spotlight, search, plist

Is there a way to search for all property list files that contain a certain string? Spotlight doesn't search *inside* .plist files.  Yes, I have 'System Files Are Included'.

For example, say a plist (the name of which is unknown) contains `<string>abc</string>`. Is there a way to search through the entire Mac for and output the file location of said plist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (Freeware) will find anything.

It will be slow, because it doesn't use an index, it searches file by file - but it will find it if it's there.

[No affiliation, just a satisfied user]

Comment: What happens if the plist is binary?

Comment: then maybe you'd have to search for it in binary. It's not a situation I've ever encountered... nor ever expect to.

Comment: I’ll second the use of EasyFind. It’s a great app, that I find myself using often.  It will search any kind of file, including binary ones.

Comment: If you use EasyFind, make sure you click the Settings button, and make sure that the line containing “plist” is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in defaults command has the option: `/usr/bin/defaults find word`

From the man page:

> Searches for word in the domain names, keys, and values of the user's defaults, and prints out a list of matches.

Comment: The OP asked "Is there a way to search through the entire Mac for and output the file location of said plist?" and while the `defaults find word` command can find a match, that command as is doesn't output the file location as requested in the OP. It also does not search the entire filesystem as requested.